# How to manage 2 tableviews in 1 viewController?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, delegates

Does anyone know a simple way to manage several tableViews in one viewController?
Here is how I've been doing it so far:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
if(tableView == self.tableView1) 
return 1;
else if(tableView == self.tableView2) 
return 2;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if(tableView == self.tableView1) 
return @"bla";
else if(tableView == self.tableView2) 
return @"blabla";
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(tableView == self.tableView1) 
...
else if(tableView == self.tableView2) 
...
}
```

I find it really annoying that I have to use an if/else statement for EVERY SINGLE delegate method. Plus, it is really hard to read when there are many tableViews. Besides, I have the same problem with NSURLConnection, etc... As soon as I have several objects that respond to the same delegate protocol, things get messy.

What is the best way to make things simpler?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use selectors and some kind of identifier for the table views (the `UIView` tag, for example). Something like this:

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"tableView%d:titleForHeaderInSection:", tableView.tag])];
}
```

Of course you will need to have one method for each of your table views. Suppose your two tables have a the tags 100 and 101, you will have then `tableView100:titleForHeaderInSection` and `tableView101:titleForHeaderInSection`.

Comment: That is quite convenient! Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

One method which I have often used is to actually have the delegates and data source for the two `UITableView`s be different objects. This way, your view controller doesn't have to switch back and forth, and your code is overall cleaner and simpler.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll do that next time I have to handle several delegating  objects. Thanks.