# how to use more than two UITableView in single view controller in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am using two `UITableView`s in a `UIViewController`, how can I populate the row and cells in both tableviews? When I give for the second tableview it says the duplicate declaration of the number of rows in section etc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's why the dataSource/delegate methods have a `tableView` parameter. Depending on its value, you can return different numbers/cells/...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == _myTableViewOutlet1)
        return 10;
    else
        return 20;
}
```

Comment: and then how to given cell text values and didSelect row method

Comment: All datasource/delegate methods have a `tableView` parameter. Not only `numberOfRowsInSection`, but also `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 2):

All of your `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDatasource` methods will be implemented only once. You just need to check for which table view the method is being called.

```
if (tableView == tblView1) {
    //Implementation for first tableView
}
else {
    //Implementation for second tableView
}
```

this will work in all of TableView's delegate and datasource methods as `tableView` is common parameter in all of your methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {}
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086974/how-to-manage-2-tableviews-in-1-viewcontroller) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907367/how-to-create-multiple-table-view-in-a-view-controller-for-ipad)

[This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416372/multiple-uitableviews-on-one-uiview) also has the solution of your issue.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look.

First create two tableview in interface builder and then connect with two IBOutlet variables and set delegate and datasource for both the tableviews.

In Interface file

```
 -IBOutlet UITableView *tableView1;
 -IBOutlet UITableView *tableView2;
```

In Implementation file

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  {
       if (tableView==tableView1)
       {
        return 1;
       }
       else 
       {
         return 2;
       }
  }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
 {
    if (tableView==tableView1)
    {
         return 3;
    }
    else
    {
         if (section==0)
          {
            return 2;
          }
          else
          {
            return 3;
          }
     }
  }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
  {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) 
            {
                  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }

    if (tableView==tableView1)
         {
           //cell for first table
         }
    else 
         {
           //cell for second table
          }
    return cell;
 }
```

Use this code. hope helps

Answer (score 1):

It is possible,look at the reference code here: http://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples

Please also refer this page : [2 tableview on a single view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489238/2-tableview-on-a-single-view)