# Two UIViewtable in One View

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I'm building an RSS apps. In this apps i create horizontal table for the news source, and in other uitableview will load the list of news from the rss feed based on the user selection in horizontal table.

The thing is i want to present the two tables in one view. The first table is in middle and the list of news at the center to bottom.
my issue is how to able to load the second table after user click the entry in first table, in the same view.

I'm able to do that using navigation controller, but i want to present it in same view.

Btw i also have the two tables have 2 separate datasource and delegate.

This is the code for firsttable.m file that will open a new view. Appreciate for any feedback.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSDictionary * newsSourceItem = (NSDictionary *)[_newsSourceList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


  RSSListViewController * rssListViewController = [[RSSListViewController alloc] initWithRSSURL:[newsSourceItem objectForKey:@"BlogURL"]];
[rssListViewController setTitle:[newsSourceItem objectForKey:@"BlogTitle"]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:rssListViewController animated:YES];
[rssListViewController release];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way :
**Define two tables in your.h file, & manage them with their instance.**

```
@interface VehicleViewController : UIViewController {

  UITableView *listVehicle;
  UITableView *listMaintenance;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *listVehicle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView * listMaintenance;
```

*In .m file*
*** Declare two UITableView properties, then in your various delegate methods you can do a conditional statement to see which property it is. Ex:**

1) Either with tableView object

```
if (tableView == [self listVehicle])
```

OR
* **Assign a tag to each table view, then in your various delegate methods you can do a conditional statement to see which tag it is. Ex:**

```
if ([tableView tag] == myConstantForTableA)
```

For more help check this : [Two TableViews in a single ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086974/how-to-manage-2-tableviews-in-1-viewcontroller)